# Managing data durability / file corruption

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, file-corruption

We know that hard drives have limited lifespan and data corruption happens. A hard drive may still appear to be OK and pass tests but some files may at some point start read differently to what they originally were just due to the medium physics/deterioration.

Data backups/mirroring solve the problem of complete disk failure, but not the problem of *silent* data corruption. Moreover, if the source/master disk gets some files corrupted, the correct versions on the backup disks will be overwritten on the next backup essentially spreading the error and making the originals unrecoverable.

In 2017, what techniques/solutions are there to address the problem *on premises* (as opposed to uploading data archives into the cloud with 99.999...% durability)?

I heard of software that basically tracks files' checksums and detects when they change, but I am wondering if there is a more low-level (e.g. filesystem-level) solution? For example, a filesystem that calculates file checksums every time files/blocks are written/updated and supports checksum verification to detect corrupted ones so that action can be taken before the error gets spread onto backup media?

Finally, maybe there is some sort of completely different approach to the problem that I am not aware about?

Comment: Some newer filesystems like btrfs implement algorithms to prevent bitrot. https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/bitrot-and-atomic-cows-inside-next-gen-filesystems/

Answer (score 2):

ZFS is basically designed to do just this.  It checksums each block of data and, if corrupted, restores it from other parts of the "Virtual RAID" (ZFS prefers to do its own equivalent of RAID, rather then use hardware RAID).

One of the functions in ZFS is to do a periodic scrub, which is the process of going through the disk and checking it for errors.

**ZFS is both a block and filesystem level solution (Its a different paradigm to having a file system on a block device on RAID type solution).**

I also note that most RAID systems will also allow perodic verification at the block level, but its not as robust, and could actually overwrite good data with bad.   For more research on this minefield (which ZFS bypasses), google  "Write Hole"

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a round about way to manage things, but I have found the best (*most effective with least amount of resources*) way to manage data against "durability and data corruption" is to both have properly managed disk arrays and have a proper backup and versioning scheme in place.

Checksums used by ZFS and BTRFS array/filesystem combos can actively find the data corruption yes, but it does not necessarily give the "answer" of what to do about it and you may still need your backups anyways for that particular set of data.  AND Scrubs on other arrays can find the data corruption also to ensure your arrays will rebuild.  Also, battery backups and Write-Intent-Bitmaps can handle the write hole problem.  Overall, modern storage systems are extremely robust, if implemented correctly, to handle the problems you will actually run into.

If data corruption were a big problem that checksumming array/filesystem combos were the answer, then ALL large enterprise firms would only use and check summing array/filesystem combos and in reality this is NOT the case.  Instead they have a robust infrastructure with redundant SANs and switches, battery backups, generators, power conditioners, time-tested file systems, well managed arrays, and backups, backups, backups!

The reality is it is an extremely rare case that what little data corruption makes it through will ACTUALLY causes a real problem; and it happens so rarely, that personally I have found it is better to rely on proper systems administration to mitigate it then actively try to manage data corruption itself.  I know over the last 20 years I've had a few files, usually media files, that randomly do not work and I assume it is data corruption.  But not once have I had a file that actually was needed not work, and IF I did, I would just go to my backups for that file, and IF that did not work, my life would go on!

Further, I cannot think of a single file that would be an end all for my personal life or business; NOT ONE.  An upset client?  A missing piece of information in a lawsuit where I am honest and just need to prove it?  A corrupted personal memory?  These all are things I would prefer to avoid, but all of these things are only worth a limited amount of my personal time and money to mitigate given that chance is near 0 they will actually happen from data corruption... EVER.

Point being, in my opinion the best thing you can do to "Manage data durability / file corruption" for smaller setups is:

- Run your arrays how it makes sense for your circumstances
- Scrub them REGULARLY to help ensure proper rebuilds in the event of drive failure
- Use battery backed hardware controllers or write-intent-bitmaps for software arrays
- Use non-parity arrays if possible to avoid rebuild failures if a URE or something happens between scrubs
- And most ciritcal,  **put in place a proper backup and versioning scheme.**

**Essentially proper systems administration is what handles the data corruption problem.**